# Can the JavaScript engine garbage collect objects passed to Rust?

Tags: javascript, garbage-collection, rust

When using Rust in a browser, I can get JavaScript objects and use them inside Rust (using, for instance, the `js!` macro from the [stdweb library](https://github.com/koute/stdweb)).

Can the JavaScript engine garbage collect these objects while I am using them (creating invalid pointers)?

Comment: Isn't the rust code transpiled to js? If so, there is no difference between js / rust code.

Comment: No, rust is compiled to [web assembly](https://webassembly.org/).

Comment: There is no gc in webassembly as there is no heap.

Comment: Webassembly has no gc but it has heap. It was JavaScript that allocated the memory for these objects and it may or may not eventually garbage collect them.

Comment: *It was javascript that allocated them* you cannot access js objects from. Web assembly?!

Comment: You can access them from web assembly, what I want to know is how they behave in relation to ownership: Do they get reclaimed by JavaScript? When does this happens?

Comment: My hypothesis is no, they won't be collected, otherwise the JS engine could break the WebAssembly module. I am hypothesizing that WebAssembly engine designers won't let the garbage collector arbitrarily break code that is running in WASM, and will consider it to be that the WASM module contains a reference to the JS object therefore the object can't be collected. I could be wrong, but that's the first thing I would've thought about if I were on the WebAssembly team of one of the browsers.